After button click in MAIN world return a value from MAIN world of a website to Chrome Extension popup.js
I have a popup.js file that has a button say Button_p. On clicking Button_p, I inject a script inject.js to a website using
// snap from popup.js
Button_p.addEventListener('click', () => {
  func();
});

function func(){
    let queryOptions = { active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true };
      let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query(queryOptions);
      console.log(tab);
      chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        target: {tabId: tab.id},
        files: ["inject.js"],
        world: 'MAIN'
      })
      .then( <SECTION to FILL> {store the parsedText} )
}

Now the inject.js creates a textarea and a button Button_D in the DOM. The target is on clicking Button_D it parses the text using parseText function and then return the parsed value parsedText back to func of popup.js .
// snap from inject.js

function Func(){
    // 1. Create Textarea
    // 2. Create Button_D
    Button_D.onclick = parseText;
    .
    .
    .
    return parsedText
}
Func()

I think it may need some promise to return from Func that this <SECTION to FILL> {store the parsedText} ) potion will be filled up with. But I am unable to implement that .
Can anybody help?

Remove world: 'MAIN', remove .then( line, and use messaging (chrome.runtime.sendMessage inside parseText and chrome.runtime.onMessage in popup.js).

@woxxom, I need world: 'MAIN'. The parsedText contains some information along with the value from textarea that cannot be retrieved in non-isolated execution of the inject.js script. Had it not been the case your solution would pretty much work.

Use "Send messages from web pages" section in the messaging article I've linked.

@woxxom Thanks! it works!! I am a bit confused even after seeing this answer. Because I need to add the Extension ID in content script , if I eventually submit it chrome store along with key in manifest won't they assign a new key after validation? In that case, how can I dynamically assign the extension ID?

You can pass the id using args: [chrome.runtime.id], func: id => { /*the code of your Func*/ } instead of using files with a separate inject.js.

An Workaround: First inject the id to the localStorage taking help of a simple function as you have mentioned using chrome.scripting.executeScript and then do the usual using files. @woxxom Thanks..
